# How can I define multiple url helpers for same route entry in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am working on Rails 4.

I have the following entry in my `routes`:

```
get 'dashboard', as: :dashboard, to: "dashboard#index"
```

which generates for me the url helpers: `dashboard_path` and `dashboard_url`

How can I define extra url helpers for same route? I would like to have, for example, the url helpers: `signed_in_defalt_path` and `signed_in_default_url` (in addition to the ones with `dashboard` prefix).

So, I would like to be able to do something like that:

```
get 'dashboard', as: [:dashboard, :signed_in_default], to: "dashboard#index"
```

but obviously this does not work.

Any clue what might be the best approach on this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kunashir is mentioning the right thing - 
if its necessary to have one route available through more named routes you need to define them individually.

But it can be DRY as follows:

```
[:dashboard, :signed_in_default].each do |helper|
  get 'dashboard', as: helper, to: "dashboard#index"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, You may add extra record to route.rb:
get 'signed_in_defaout', as: :signed_in_default, to: "dashborad#inded".